# How to get all list titles on a page

Tags: web-part, farm-solution

I need to get all of the list titles on a SharePoint 2013 page and display them in a properties box for editing so that a person can select which list to bind to.
Im using site.rootWeb.Lists and its returning all kinds of funky things.
Here's how im getting the lists:

```
    private void GetListNames()
    {
        Guid siteId = SPContext.Current.Site.ID;
        Guid webId = SPContext.Current.Web.ID;
        SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate
        {
            using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteId))
            {
                using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb(webId))
                {
                    foreach (SPList aList in web.Lists)
                    {
                        if (aList.BaseTemplate == SPListTemplateType.Announcements)
                        {
                            _lists.Add(aList.Title);
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        });
    }
```

and heres how im trying to get a list for when the control is in edit view (its not working at all)

```
[Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared), WebBrowsable(true),
WebDisplayName("Lists"),
WebDescription("Lists to choose to scroll")]
public Collection<string> AvailableLists
{
    get
    {
        return _lists;
    }
    set
    {
        _lists = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Would a drop down list work for you in the Properties pane?

Comment: Yes but that requires an enum, i can't make it out of a string collection